# Laravel 5 cache on file not working

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5

I have machine with `php 5.6`  `laravel 5` `centos 7.3` `apache httpd 2.4`.

I try use `laravel` cache `config/cache.php`:

```
...
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
...
'file' => [
        'driver' => 'file',
        'path'   => storage_path('framework/cache'),
    ],
...
```

but get error:

> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/project/api/storage/framework/cache/7d/ab/7dabe30eba211b803662f3a2c48133024bb4aa18): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

when create file manually:

```
[user cache]$ mkdir 7d
[user cache]$ cd ./7d/ 
[user 7d]$ mkdir ab
[user cache]$ cd ./ab/
[user 7d]$ touch 7dabe30eba211b803662f3a2c48133024bb4aa18
```

and then get permissions problems.

> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/project/api/storage/framework/cache/7d/ab/7dabe30eba211b803662f3a2c48133024bb4aa18):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

permisions:

```
[user api]$ stat -c "%a %n" ./storage/framework/cache/
777 ./storage/framework/cache/

[user api]$ ls -l./storage/framework/cache/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 3 user user 62 Feb  8 10:25 7d
```

Comment: Do you have a writable folder `/var/www/html/project/api/storage/framework/cache/` on your system?

Comment: What's the code for "create file manually"?

Comment: Is your webserver using the same user as the cli you created file with? don't see you applying any file permissions like `chown` or `chmod` on the created file either.

Comment: cache folder has 777 permissions. Webserver work as Apache user.